# Change expiration time of password reset link magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to change expiration time of reset link.

Got the setting to change the expiration time from Admin panel . "Recovery Link Expiration Period (Hours)" But it's in hours and i want to change it to minutes 
Similar question had been raised on Magento 1.7 but i am unable to find similar resolution for magento 2.

[Change expiration time of password reset link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9244/change-expiration-time-of-password-reset-link/9370?noredirect=1#comment367469_9370)

Comment: Did you try like this: 0.30 for 30mins or 0.01 for 1 minute. Try this.

Comment: You need to create your own module for that in which you need to provide hours and minutes option in admin configuration. Then you need to override isResetPasswordLinkTokenExpired() method of Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement class. Put your customized code inside this method. I haven't tried this thing, but tips may help you.

Comment: You can use around plugin for function override isResetPasswordLinkTokenExpired function

Comment: @John thx it works but if did from core_config_data and not via panel.

Comment: you mean you added it in core_config_data table? for which key you have added it?

Comment: @Suman for creating plugin we have to override the function but same function is written in 3 different models .hence it's creating confusion as Label (Hours ) was changed to minutes in vendor/magento/magento-backend/i18n/en_Us.csv but after changing the code in isResetPasswordLinkTokenExpired() it did not worked.

Comment: @John customer/password/reset_link_expiration_period just  SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path  LIKE '%customer/password/reset_link_expiration_period%'
.

Comment: Hope after changing vendor or overriding model i have execute 1>  bin/magento setup:di:compile
2> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: gotcha! that was the same field which got updated from admin section, you make direct entry in table which is not good. If its not updating then something went wrong. Anyways, its good that it works for you.

Comment: Ya , but how to update it from admin panel that's my main question by overriding which module

Comment: see my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From admin panel, it doesn't allow user to add a number less than 1, for example if someone wants to add time in minutes. This was the file from where it comes from

*/var/www/html/projectName/vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<field id="reset_link_expiration_period" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Recovery Link Expiration Period (hours)</label>
                    <comment>Please enter a number 1 or greater in this field.</comment>
                    <validate>required-entry validate-digits validate-digits-range digits-range-1-</validate>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Backend\Password\Link\Expirationperiod</backend_model>
                </field>
```

As you can see, it has

```
<validate>required-entry validate-digits validate-digits-range digits-range-1-</validate>
```

which validate the field, to not to accept number less than one. To achieve this, first you need to override this system.xml file by 
[How to override system.xml core file in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141077/how-to-override-system-xml-core-file-in-magento2)

and update validate by this

```
                <validate>required-entry validate-digits</validate>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thx @john I changed it to    <validate>required-entry integer validate-greater-than-zero</validate> Path app/code/hpol/customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml and executed 3 command 1> bin/magento setup:upgrade 
2> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 3>   bin/magento setup:di:compile
 But its not reflecting on admin panel. Hope i am doing some silly mistake . Could you please help me in this

Comment: In your this module, add <module name="Magento_Customer"/> in your  module.xml file. See this link for more reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141077/how-to-override-system-xml-core-file-in-magento2  Also i have noticed that you are adding validation of greater than zero, it will also not allow you to add time in minutes.

Comment: it works but in backend it does not saves as 0.5 i.e 30 min. Instead it saves a 1 by default.

Comment: yes, because you have added validate-greater-than-zero this validation. remove it and try it again.

Comment: it works but in backend it does not saves as 0.5 i.e 30 min. Instead it saves a 1 by default. Script which does this Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Backend\Password\Link\Expirationperiod

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen to override function which save config value 
  Create a Folder Customer 
Path : App/code/Desiredname/Customer
create folders etc,i18n,Model and file registration.php

> Path/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Desiredname_Customer" setup_version="1.1.6">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> Path/app/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
<group id="password" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

            <field id="reset_link_expiration_period" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label>Recovery Link Expiration Period (hours)</label>
                <comment>Please enter a number 1 or greater in this field.</comment>
                <validate>required-entry validate-greater-than-zero</validate>
                <backend_model>Desiredname\Customer\Plugin\Model\Config\Backend\Password\Link\Expirationperiod</backend_model>
            </field>
            </group>
   </system>
</config>
```

> This two lines are important

```
<validate>required-entry validate-greater-than-zero</validate>
                <backend_model>Desiredname\Customer\Plugin\Model\Config\Backend\Password\Link\Expirationperiod</backend_model>
```

> Path\Plugin\Model\Config\Backend\Password\Link\Expirationperiod

Above will allow to insert value in decimals but while saving there is PHP validation to check decimal values and value below 1. Hence had to override this functionality

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Desiredname\Customer\Plugin\Model\Config\Backend\Password\Link;

/**
 * Customer Reset Password Link Expiration period backend model
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */


class Expirationperiod extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    /**
     * Validate expiration period value before saving
     *
     * @return $this
     */
     public function beforeSave()
    {
        parent::beforeSave();
        $resetPasswordLinkExpirationPeriod = (float)$this->getValue();
        $this->setValue((string)$resetPasswordLinkExpirationPeriod);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> To change Label at admin level

Path/i18n/en_US.csv

```
"Please enter a number 1 or greater in this field.","Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field."
```